# Ajax não retorna o data das requisiçoes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Realizo uma consulta com ajax em uma pagina php, o problema é que mesmo pedindo para retornar dados, o 'data' do ajax não retorna nada, dou um alert no 'data' e ele me retorna um alerta em branco, codigo JS abaixo:

```
$(function(){

    $(".logando").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        if($("#email").val() == "" || $("#senha").val() == "") {
            $(".obrigatorio").slideDown(500).css("display","block");
        }
        else {

            var emailUsuario =  $("#email").val();
            var senhaUsuario =  $("#senha").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "../../controller/Logar_Cadastrar.inc.php",
                data: {email: emailUsuario, senha: senhaUsuario},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

                beforeSend: function() {
                    $(".obrigatorio").slideDown(100).html("Carregando");
                },

                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            })
        }
    })

})
```

Codigo do bloco de login pagina HTML:

```
<form action="../../controller/Logar_Cadastrar.inc.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="Digite seu e-mail..." id="email"><br>
      <input type="password" name="senha" required placeholder="Digite sua senha..." id="senha"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="logar">
      <input type="submit" value="Logar-se" class="logando"><br>
</form>
```

Codigo da pagina PHP:

```
<?php

require_once('../model/Logar_Cadastrar.class.php');
$logarCadastrar = new Logar;

//Função para logar
if(isset($_POST['logar'])):
    $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $senha = trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha']));

    $verificar = $logarCadastrar->Consulta("SELECT * FROM CS_usuarios WHERE email = ? AND senha = ?","ss","{$email}","{$senha}");
    if($verificar >= 1):
        // return "Encontrado";
        echo "Encontrado";
    else:
        // return "Não encontrado";
        echo "Não encontrado";
    endif;
endif;
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta seu código HTML e o PHP. Fica impossível responder sem o código completo

Comment: Pronto, editei.

Comment: Aparentemente o  `if(isset($_POST['logar']))` não está sendo satisfeito, então o código dentro do `if` não será executado. Uma possível solução é tirar este `if(isset($_POST['logar']))` ou passar a uma variável `logar` no ajax: `data: {email: emailUsuario, senha: senhaUsuario, logar:sim}`

Comment: Continua sem retornar nada, já ate mudei a url mas continua sem funcionar

Comment: O `dataType: "json"` diz ao jQuery que o seu PHP vai retornar JSON. Mas você não está retornando JSON.

Comment: pode me dar um exemplo de como proceder ?

Comment: Tenta com `dataType: "html"` e vê se vem a resposta do php.

Comment: Seguindo a linha do @bfavaretto, mantenha seu código JavaScript como está e no PHP vc substitui os "echos" por: `echo json_encode(['retorno' => 'Encontrado'])` e `echo json_encode(['retorno' => 'Não Encontrado'])` -  A solução é para PHP 5.4 ou sup. Se o seu PHP for inferior, terá que colocar o array() ao invés dos colchetes.

Comment: Mas antes de tudo vc deve passar um parametro "logar" no seu ajax ou retirar aquele IF, conforme avaliou a @AmandaLima. Do jeito que está não passa no IF.

Comment: Galera muito obrigado, eu consegui graças a ajuda de todos vocês, precisei usar a if como a Amanda me disse, e precisei seguir a dica do bfavaretto e de resto usei o json_encode como o Marco me recomendou, agora esta tudo funcionando perfeitamente, foi bom que obtive uma boa esperiência com isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que você possa receber o data no json é necessário que você retorne um JSON do PHP para que ele chegue no seu método success do Ajax, tanto é que se você executar a função error do ajax, você vai receber uma mensagem de erro:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url:  "../../controller/Logar_Cadastrar.inc.php",
            data: {email: emailUsuario, senha: senhaUsuario},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            beforeSend: function() {
                $(".obrigatorio").slideDown(100).html("Carregando");
            },

            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }, error: function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

Para que o seu código possa funcionar, adicione na sua linha que está printando o Encontrado, o json_encode. Da seguinte forma:

```
require_once('../model/Logar_Cadastrar.class.php');
$logarCadastrar = new Logar;

//Função para logar
if(isset($_POST['logar'])):
   $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
   $senha = trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha']));
   $verificar = $logarCadastrar->Consulta("SELECT * FROM CS_usuarios WHERE email = ? AND senha = ?","ss","{$email}","{$senha}");
   if($verificar >= 1):
       // return "Encontrado";
       print_r(json_encode("Encontrado"));
   else:
       // return "Não encontrado";
       print_r(json_encode("Não encontrado"));
   endif;
  endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu ajax esta esperando um retorno do tipo JSON, no PHP faça o seguinte:

```
echo json_encode("Aqui o que deseja retornar");
```